# how to replace osgi configuration properties through aem dialog

Tags: java, annotations, osgi, aem

I searched below blogs,but I didn't find exact solution,initially i configured OSGI configuration properties through java class, and i want replace these values from dialog input.

- [Reading Adobe Experience Manager OSGi Configuration Values](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/osgi_config.html)
- [Reading OSGi Configuration properties](http://adobeaemclub.com/reading-osgi-configuration-properties/)

Comment: are you expecting component dialog or Felix console configuration dialog ?

Comment: yes i am expecting component Dialog

Answer (score 2):

OSGI property can be configured by an OSGI service configuration dialog.
E.g.

- link for configuration of `AEMFormsManagerConfiguration` on local authoring env will be
  http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.adobe.aem.formsndocuments.config.AEMFormsManagerConfiguration
- Or for your class `com.my.package.MyClass`
  http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.my.package.MyClass

All configuration you can find on a special  [OSGI Configuration](http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr) tab

Comment: thanks for reply, i want replace osgi configuration properties from component dialog

Answer (score 1):

Your service must have the `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service` and optionally  `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component` annotations.

Use the `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties` and `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property` as in the example below:

```Java
@Properties({
        @Property(
                label = "Some Property",
                description = "Some custom property",
                name = "myComponent.property",
                value = "default value"
        )
})
```

After your service is deployed, you can go to /system/console/configMgr of your AEM instance and modify the properties using the dynamically generated properties dialog. This is the default bahaviour of the system.

Hope this helps.